# Конвертирование из MSSQL в MySQL. Как?

Tags: база-данных, конвертация, sql-server, mysql

Возник такой вопрос, как сконвертировать бд из формата MSSQL в формат MySQL? Нашел пару ресурсов-программ, которые позволяют это сделать, но для них требуется поднятый сервер MSSQL, которого ессно у меня нет. Вопрос об установке MSSQL не рассматривается, так как это последний вариант.

На руках есть дамп базы данных, можно ли его сконвертировать в MySQL без поднятого MSSQL сервера?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это не последний вариант, а единственный. 
Я сомневаюсь, что есть софт, который способен разобрать формат бэкапа MS SQL, тем более, что такой софт не имеет смысла - развернуть MS SQL достаточно просто, тем более что есть бесплатная версия, правда, с ограничением на размер базы, и триал на 180 дней без ограничения.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо, значит будем поднимать.